# Background image covering all of the content

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve an effect similar to the background image in Twitter mobile website for iPhone/Android ([screenshot of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ix9dn.png)).

My solution works when the content fits the screen, but if there is a scroll it breaks.

This is the CSS I'm using:

```css
.welcome body{
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/DQ59KbW.jpg) no-repeat top left;
  z-index: -1;
  background-clip: border-box;
  -webkit-background-clip: border-box;
  background-origin: padding-box;
  -webkit-background-origin: padding-box;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
}

html.welcome, .welcome body{
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your background not to scroll:

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

Re: your comment, change your CSS to:

```
html { 
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/DQ59KbW.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -o-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

This will be full-screen, at any size, and not scroll.

Only caveat is it won't work with non-CSS3 browsers (should work in any Chrome, Firefox 3.6+, IE8+ and Opera 10+).

Comment: Well, that makes it not ugly, but still not ideal! I wanted to make the background image height equal to the content height. Not sure if I'm being clear. Thanks for help though!

Comment: @GuilhermeBerger - Edited the answer, should be what you're looking for.

Comment: Actually, I wanted it to scroll with the content. But thinking about it again, the last button is linked to an accordion, and that would set a new height for the content. I'm not sure we could work out my solution. I'll use either of those. Thanks!

Comment: If it scrolls with the content then there'd be no way for it to fit if your content is too large for it. This way, it just sits static and your content scrolls over it.

Answer (score 0):

What behaviour do you intend? If the content is larger than the background image is tall, then it simply won't work out. You could add a position:fixed to the body if that is what you want to achieve.

Comment: I wanted to make the background image height equal to the content height. Not sure if I'm being clear.